# Parsing html page content without using selector

Tags: html, css, xml, xpath, html-parsing

I am going to parse some web pages using Java program. For this purpose I wrote a small code for parsing page content by using xpath as selector. For parsing different sites you need to find the appropriate xpath per each site. The problem is for doing that you need an operator to find the write xpath for you. (for example using firepath firefox addon) Suppose you dont know what page you should parse or the number of sites get really big for operator to find right xpath. In this case you need a way for parsing pages without using any selector. (same scenario exist for CSS selector) Or there should be a way to find xpath automatically! I was wondering what is the method of parsing web pages in this way?
Here is the small code which I wrote for this purpose, please feel free to extend that in presenting your solutions.

```
public downloadHTML(String url) throws IOException{
        CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties();

        // set some properties to non-default values
        props.setTranslateSpecialEntities(true);
        props.setTransResCharsToNCR(true);
        props.setOmitComments(true);

        // do parsing
        TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(
            new URL(url)
        );

        // serialize to xml file
        new PrettyXmlSerializer(props).writeToFile(
            tagNode, "c:\\TEMP\\clean.xml", "utf-8"
        );
    }


public static void testJavaxXpath(String pattern)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
            FileNotFoundException, XPathExpressionException {

        DocumentBuilder b = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = b.parse(new FileInputStream(
                "c:\\TEMP\\clean.xml"));

        // Evaluate XPath against Document itself
        javax.xml.xpath.XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(pattern,
                doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i) {
            Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            System.out.println(e.getFirstChild().getTextContent());
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't know what XPath expression to use, what *do* you know? Is there a particular string or id you want to look for?

Comment: @LarsH I know I want to parse a content of blog post. But I dont know what is the blog so xpath or css for that blog is unknown!

Comment: Aside from not knowing what blog you're going to look at, do you know what you're going to look for in the blog post? XPath is not an XML parser; it's for selecting specific things out of a document structure after parsing. You're already parsing the document with `b.parse()`. Now you need to decide what you're looking for in the parsed structure (`doc`). For example, the Firepath Firefox add-on requires that you tell it what element you're trying to select.

Comment: @LarsH I know I want to parse post content, and post title and post date out of blog page, but the problem is each blog has its own structure of page, I can not reach to a specific xpath that works on all blogs!

Comment: Yeah, the HTML output structure would be quite different for each. The best approach I could suggest would be to pick the top 3 or so popular blog formats (Wordpress, etc.) and work on an XPath expression for each item you want, then union them using the `|` operator. If you want help on the union aspect, post your XPath expressions for e.g. title for specific blogs here, and we can help with putting them together.

Comment: @LarsH So There is no other way? Actually in blog world every structure is possible so there is no way to make sure about having a xpath pattern for all of them! Maybe I should go for Natural Language Processing methods for this purpose. Or at least find a way to extract Xpath from blog post automatically!

Comment: The question as it stands is too broad to ask smby here to solve it for you. If you want to give a few example blog pages, somebody could suggest some heuristics for finding the title, date, and content in general. But no it's not possible in general to do this automatically for all possible blog formats.